# Including a class in an ajax PHP function causes a crash

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax function that calls `ajax.php` for a specific function, and when it is called, I want to include a class, but when I do, it causes the request to crash and return this error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

This is my PHP code:

```
$ajax_action = _POST('ajax');
if($ajax_action == "gwonline")
{
    $isonlinestr = '<span class="fa fa-circle" style="color:red"></span> Offline';
    $isonline = false;
    include './include/SampQueryAPI.php';
    $server = new SampQueryAPI("37.59.60.13", 7778);
    if(isset($server) && $server->isOnline())
    {
        $sInfo = $server->getInfo();
        $isonline = true;
        if($sInfo != -1)
        {
            if(isset($sInfo['players']) && isset($sInfo['maxplayers']))
            {
                $basicPlayers = $sInfo['players'];
                $maxPlayers = $sInfo['maxplayers'];
            }
            $isonlinestr =  '<span class="fa fa-circle" style="color:green"></span> Online<br>Players Online: ' . issetordefault($basicPlayers, "0") . "/" . issetordefault($maxPlayers, "0");
        }
    }
    $server->__destruct();
    $return = json_encode(array("isonline" => $isonline, "isonlinestr" => $isonlinestr));
    exit($return);
}
```

It crashes when I call `include`. I tried to include `./include/SampQueryAPI.php'`, `SampQueryAPI.php` and `./SampQueryAPI.php`.

`ajax.php` is in the folder as `SampQueryAPI.php`, so it should be the last one, but none of them work. Is that not possible to include in an ajax request?

Comment: if ajax.ph and SampQueryAPI.php are in same page why do you include like './include/SampQueryAPI.php'?

Comment: `include 'SampQueryAPI.php';` should work fine.

Comment: I said I tried with all three paths written below the code, none works.

Comment: Have you checked for any errors in `SampQueryAPI.php` ? Also show javascript code which is sending `AJAX` request.

Comment: There is no error in `SampQueryAPI.php` because I use it when loading the page (prior to using the ajax call). When debugging, the debug stops right after the include without saying anything.

Comment: @OmerAviv why you call `$server->__destruct();` **Destructor** method will be called automatically when the script is executed

Comment: If you are using apache, have a look at error logs.

Comment: The `__destruct()` function closes the socket. Anyway, I fixed the problem, thanks though!